# WebViewでJavaScriptのダイアログを表示させたい

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, android-webview

```
package com.example.makki.webviewex;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class WebViewEx extends ActionBarActivity {

    //メニューアイテムID
    private static final int MENU_ITEM0 = 0;
    private static final int MENU_ITEM1 = 1;
    private static final int MENU_ITEM2 = 2;
    private static final int MENU_ITEM3 = 3;
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view_ex);

        //Weビューの作成
        webView = new WebView(this);
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(false);

        //リンクをタップしたときに標準ブラウザを起動させない
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        //Weビューの通知リクエストの処理
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            //URジャンプ時前に呼ばれる
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                //外部ブラウザではなく内部ブラウザを利用
                return false;
            }

            //エラー時に呼ばれる
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                        String description, String url) {
                toast("通信エラーです。");
            }
        });
        setContentView(webView);

        //HTMの読み込み
        webView.loadUrl("http://hakuhin.jp/js/dialog.html#DIALOG_00");
    }

    //トーストの表示
    private void toast(String text) {
        if (text == null) text = "";
        Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    //オプションメニューの生成
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_web_view_ex, menu);

        //オプションメニューへのアイテム0追加
        MenuItem item0 = menu.add(0, MENU_ITEM0, 0, "ログイン");
        item0.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);

        //オプションメニューへのアイテム0追加
        MenuItem item1 = menu.add(0, MENU_ITEM1, 0, "項目１");
        item0.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);

        //オプションメニューへのアイテム0追加
        MenuItem item2 = menu.add(0, MENU_ITEM2, 0, "項目２");
        item0.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);

        //オプションメニューへのアイテム0追加
        MenuItem item3 = menu.add(0, MENU_ITEM3, 0, "押してはいけない");
        item0.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        if (itemId == MENU_ITEM0) {
            toast("ログインを押した");
            webView.loadUrl("https://accounts.google.com/login?hl=ja");

            webView.reload();
        } else if (itemId == MENU_ITEM3) {
            toast("ダメよダメダメ");
        }

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (itemId == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

質問です。
`WebView`でJavaScriptのダイアログを表示させるには何が必要でしょうか？

プロジェクトのMinimumSDKは4.1にしてあります。本体のバージョンは5.1.1でクロームから
ダイアログは表示されます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

の設定がないのが原因かと思います。`WebChromeClient`については、[公式の`WebView`のリファレンス](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)を参照ください。

---

余談ですが、Android5.0以降では、`WebView`はSDKの一部ではなくなり、`Android System WebView`として外部から提供されるようになりました。これは`WebView`起因の脆弱性に対し、古いOS（といっても5.0以降に限定されますが）でも対応可能にするためだと思います。

この`Android System WebView`の一部のバージョンだと[`JavaScript`からのアラート表示が機能しない](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=447607)という不都合が報告されています。現在では修正されているはずなので、本件には関係ないかと思います。