# AndroidのWebViewでalertやconfirmの本文が真っ白になってしまう

Tags: android

WebView上で特定のWebサイトを表示させるAndroidアプリの開発をしています。
どうにかアプリは完成したのですが、Android6、7の端末で、Webサイト内のalertやconfirmが動いたときにダイアログ内の本文が真っ白になっており、「キャンセル」や「OK」しか表示されませんでした。
Android4、5では正常にalertもconfirmも表示されており、また本文が真っ白であってもalert, confirmともに正常に動作しています。

同じような事象に遭遇された方で、解決策をご存知の方がいらっしゃればお知恵を拝借したく存じます。
何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 上記のアプリとは別に、WebViewの機能のみを持ったシンプルな別アプリを作って試してみましたが、そちらではAndroid6,7でもalert, confirmのダイアログ本文が表示されました。特定の状況下、例えばXMLレイアウトの組み込み方などが原因でAndroid6,7でのみダイアログ本文が表示されなくなったりしてしまうのでしょうか。。引き続きよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185427/alert-dialog-text-color-using-styles
このサイトのやり方でダイアログだけtextColorを変更することができました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

styleの設定がWebViewにまで影響するので見直すと良いかもしれません。

Comment: stylesのtextColorPrimaryを見直したら思い通りの表示ができました。
ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0):

webViewのWebChromeClientをセットしていますか？

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

同様の質問：[WebViewでJavaScriptのダイアログを表示させたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12986/)

Comment: はい。確認しましたが、セットしています。